# BEGIN TRANSACTION error when a R/O sqlite database is attached to a R/W database

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have two sqlite databases.  I open my main DB which is in R/W memory (iOS app Documents folder) and then ATTACH a second DB that is in R/O memory (iOS app Bundle).

Whenever I do BEGIN TRANSACTION, I immediately get "attempt to write a readonly database" even though I have no intention of changing the DB that's in readonly memory.  Is that error expected?  Is there anything I can do short of temporarily DETACH-ing to get the BEGIN TRANSACTION to work?  (I'm using FMDB.)

Comment: Setup two connections. One that is only used with `select` statements and has the read-only database attached. The second that is only used for `insert/update/delete` and does not attach the read-only database.

Comment: @maddy - thank you, that is a good solution, and it preserves the ability to do joins between databases.